# Возникает ошибка в программе при вызове Bprint - "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Моя цель - сделать очень простой терминал.

Проблема - при попытке запуска постоянно возникают ошибки. Думал дело в моем компиляторе, но даже онлайн компиляторы указывают на ошибки. Возникает ошибка при запуске функции. Вот текст ошибки:

```
Bprint ("Welcome to MPTB") 
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Сам код программы:

```
inpt = ""
inpt1 = ""

ComInd = 0
ComLst = ["print", "close"]
ComParLst = [1,0] 

Q = ""

def Qinput(q, answer1, answer2):
    Q = str(q, "(", answer1, "/", answer2, ")")
    return (str(input(Q)) == answer1)

def _print_ (t):
    print("")
    print(t)
    print("")

def Bprint(t):
    print("#MyPythonTerminalBot ", t)

def Binput(t):
    Q = str("#MyPythonTerminalBot  ", str(t))
    return (str(input(Q))

Bprint:("Welcome to MPTB")
inpt = str(Binput("Command: "))

if inpt in ComLst:
    ComInd = ComLst.index(inpt)
    if ComInd == 0:
        inpt = Binput("Parametrs: ")
    _print_(">>> ", inpt)
if ComInd == 1:
    if Qinput("Are you sure?", "Y","N"):
        Bprint("Goodbye")

if ComLst.count(inpt):
    _print_('Error1 -- Command "', inpt, '" not found')
```

Comment: Хорошо, отредактирую

Comment: Стало гораздо лучше! )

Comment: опечатка у вас. Двоеточие `:` между `Bprint` и `("Welcome to MPTB")`

Comment: Всем спасибо, ответ найден.  Да, @jfs правильно подметил что  двоеточие стоит там где не надо, но если его убрать, ошибка все равно будет. Дело в том, что в предыдущей строке: ` return (str(input(Q))` я не закрыл скобку. При её закрытии данной ошибки не происходит, но происходят другие, так что я решил переписать программу с нуля.